# Wordpress run Classifieds? a good idea?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'm building an inventory/classified for all my products onto a wordpress site. Is this a good idea?
The question i have is how to seperate them all.

I have about 50 product categories (which wont fit the menu).
 I need to find a way to query and show the items for each category out as they onto an independant page.

For example. I have engines, tires, rim, hoods. I need a page to show all engines together and not the others.

Thanks it advance, I hope the question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is fine, i am working for a company, in which i used wordpress to create an auction. It had a ton of categories and products. I created a custom post to allow users to create items for the auction. Added categories which i used to filter through the products, ie: All, Arts & Entertainment, Sports, Dining, Golf, etc.  I created pagination so it shows the products on multiple pages

Learn more about Custom post types here [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types)

Hope this helps
-David